# Arithmetic compression and decompression

Tags: java, math, compression, logarithm

I was looking into this compression trying to understand how it works, and this is what I got. It may be totally wrong tho:

Lets say we have file with content of "TEST".

Now I need to get probabilities and since this word has 3 different characters I make:

```
T -> num_of_this_char_duplicates / number_of_content_char_length = 2/4 = 0.5
E -> 1/4 = 0.25
S -> 1/4 = 0.25
```

So from 0 to 1

```
0----------------0.5--------0.75----------1
        t               e            s
```

now we search for T from TEST, t is in range from 0-0.5 and in that range, we calculate new ranges for t,e,s

the formula I found for this is `new_upper_limit = lower_limit + ((upper_limit - lower_limit) * probability)`

so new range would be:

```
   t        e            s
0----0.25-------0.375--------0.5
```

same for second char from string e which is between 0.25 and 0.375

```
      t          e             s
0.25----0.3125-------0.34375-------0.375
```

and so on for s

```
         t            e              s
0.34375----0.359375------0.3671875------0.375
```

and at last for t again

```
0.34375----0.359375
```

so last range should be compressed data? right?

So if I randomly pick number between last range lets say 0.355 and repeat the process, that number is

```
between 0 - 0.5, which gives back T letter.
Next 0.355 is between 0.25 - 0.375 which gives back letter E.
Next 0.355 is between 0.34375 - 0.375 which gives back letter S.
Last 0.355 is between 0.34375 - 0.359375 which gives back letter T.
```

So if all this is right, my questions would be:

1. On decoding part it seems like I need to store last range with
   pre-defined char probabilities to be able to decode it. Is that
   right?
2. Also on decoding part how does it know that 0.34375 - 0.359375 is last range or last char is in that range, is it from chars
   length? Like for each char, there must be sub-range, and same for
   count number? Or does it check is like last range created?

   3. If it is by char count number, do I need last range or just number between that range?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: 1. Yes, with static model the decoder needs to know the probabilities and be able to calculate ranges like the encoder. Adaptive model avoids this at cost of more computation. | 2. One option is tell the decoder how many symbols to decode. Other is to code a special symbol representing the end of data. | Not sure what exactly you mean by 3.

Comment: @DanMašek, thanks for your reply! For 3th if the last range for the last symbol is 0.34375 - 0.359375 and I need the only number between those two numbers like 0.355 to decode every other symbol by probabilities. Could I just save that one number instead of two numbers? With symbols count and probabilities, to decode it?

Comment: You'd save just one number that falls into the final interval. Since the goal is compression, you'd ideally pick the one with the shortest representation. In your example, representing it in base 10, the value of `0.35` would be a better choice than `0.355`.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, thank you! Just one more question that may be really dumb since I never done this before, and anyone I asked said the same. Sorry to bother you, if someone said compression with arithmetical coding and integer implementation. Does that mean using probability range between 0 and max_integer_value? Which limits the number of symbols right? Or integer implementation is something else?